# Test Lombok-generated data structure

Tags: java, tdd, lombok, junit5

I have the following class describing a tuple, using `lombok` for that:

```
@Data
public class Pair<K, V> {
    private final K key;
    private V value;
}
```

Then I wanted to write a test for this class, using `JUnit` as follows:

```
public class PairTest {
    @Test
    void pairCanBeCreatedAndHoldIntegerValues() {
        Pair<Integer,Integer> myTestPair = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(0);
        myTestPair.setValue(5);
        assertEquals(5, myTestPair.getValue());
        assertEquals(0, myTestPair.getKey());
    }
}
```

However despite the automatically lombok-generated get method should return an `int`, I can see my IDE complaining that:

```
Error:(12, 9) java: reference to assertEquals is ambiguous
  both method assertEquals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) in org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions and method assertEquals(int,int) in org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions match
```

Despite I *know* that `assertEquals` is expecting two `int`, which I am providing.

How can I do this in `Java`?

Comment: you can use   import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat; assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of that behaviour is called [autoboxing\unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes
>   between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper
>   classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a
>   Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is
>   called unboxing.

`myTestPair` object returns `Integer` that is wrapper for `int`, thus compiler does not know what overloaded method to use: `assertEquals(Object, Object)` or `assertEquals(int, int)`. You need to let it known to compiler, use:

```
assertEquals(5, myTestPair.getValue().intValue());
assertEquals(0, myTestPair.getKey().intValue());
```

Or

```
assertEquals((Integer)5, myTestPair.getValue());
assertEquals((Integer)0, myTestPair.getKey());
```

Or

```
assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(5), myTestPair.getValue());
assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(0), myTestPair.getKey());
```

Comment: @GhostCat, yes, sure.